# Geocoding using Google Maps - Zero Results using API, but found on map?

Tags: maps

I'm trying to get the longitude and latitude of this particular location -

> Jalan Kaki Bukit, Off Jalan Yeap Chor Ee

I used this to query Google Maps for an XML response -

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Jalan+Kaki+Bukit,+Off+Jalan+Yeap+Chor+Ee+&sensor=true

Zero results were returned. However, when I manually searched for the location on the Google Maps website, it was found -

http://bit.ly/PcV4BM

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the assumption that the API used on 'maps.google.com' is identical to Google's publicly accessible API may well be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "Off", try "At" -- I got a result with
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Jalan+Kaki+Bukit+At+Jalan+Yeap+Chor+Ee+&sensor=true